# MS Word's mistake?

Tags: relative-clauses

> This is a picture which looks nice.

In this sentence, I don't see anything wrong with the grammar.

BUT, MS Word always ... always wants 'which' to be changed to ', which' or 'that'.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Relative clauses can use either "which" or "that" as a relative pronoun.

Generally we tend to use "which" when we are describing something in a non-restrictive way. If we are adding a description like this the relative clause is set off from the rest of the sentence with a comma. In speech the sentence is broken by intonation, and perhaps a short pause.

> This is a picture, which looks nice.

means "This a picture, and it looks nice."  The pronoun in non-restrictive clauses can nearly always be replaced by "and it".

When there are several pictures and we want to identify a particular one by its description, we call this a restrictive relative clause. In this case the relative clause does not just add additional information, it is required to understand the meaning. There is no comma, and in speech the sentence is spoken as a single flow.

> Take the picture that looks nice.

Means "There are several pictures. Take the nice-looking one and leave the others."

You will find that native speakers don't always apply this rule, or use "which" with no comma in a restrictive sense. This is a style rule rather than a strict part of English Grammar. MS Word is trying to encourage you to use this style rule.

In your example, the sentence is so short that, even though it is clearly a non-restrictive relative clause, it could be spoken clearly even without a pause. The comma is optional, but MS Word is not subtle enough to analyse that.